# Heating water from one temperature to another temperature: why 1C heat time differs during the problem statement?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, water

My task states that
"Using a heater  a boy heated his tea from temperature T1 = 20◦C to T2 = 40◦C in time τ1 = 120 s. Then he poured half of the water from the cup. He warmed the remaining water from temperature T2 up to temperature T3 = 55◦C in time τ2 = 60 s.
Then he reduced 2 times the power of the heater and poured out half of the remaining water. After how much time τ3 will the remaining water heat up to for temperature T4 = 100◦C

It says that he used aluminum cup, but it also states that "aluminum is a good heat conductor. Heat losses to the surrounding environment may not be taken into account."

So before even trying to find out how to calculate it, I do not understand how it could be :

1. If he heated water from T1 = 20◦C to T2 = 40◦C in time τ1 = 120 s then he heated 20◦C in 120s.
2. It means that he can heat 1◦C in 120/20=6s.
3. This mean that from T2 to 55◦C or 15◦C he should heat water in 15*6s = 90s, but it is given 60s. *How it can be?!*

Comment: What is the heat capacity of water? Not the value, but the units (dimensions).

Comment: Joules per gram per degree celsius @JEB

Comment: I think you ignored the gram part in your analysis.